# How to limit magento 2 items at thumbnail slider for product page

Tags: magento, magento2, fotorama

I'm studing magento 2. inside product page I increased the thumbnail size by view.xml.
Now I need to set the thumbnail slider number of items, example, now is showing 5 thumbnails of the product, I need to limit to 4.

This theme using magento default fotorama

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. Do you want a vertical carousel with 4 thumbnails shown at all times or do you want to limit the displayed thumbnails to 4, ignoring excess images in your product media?

Comment: @Tobi I need to limit 4 thumbnails shown at all times and another thumbnails to be displayed normally inside the caroussel

Comment: Hello @DaviReinoldo , Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Faisal Sheikh I don't found nothing about it. I solved my problem editing the CSS of this page. I really dislike this fotorama adopted by magento.

Comment: @DaviReinoldo Yes, I agree with you, also most of the options from etc/view.xml for product gallery is not working. By the way I did it by overriding gallery block file.